# How to return an array asyc, writing a Windows Runtime Component in C++/WinRT

Tags: c++-winrt

What is the best way to asynchronously return an array from a Windows Runtime Component written in C++/WinRT, given that IAsyncOperation<TResult> is not allowed as a return type if TResult is an array?

It's possible to wrap an array inside a PropertyValue, but both boxing and unboxing the array creates copies, which seems inefficient. At the moment, what I'm doing is writing a custom component to store the com_array (which has a constructor that allows me to move in the com_array), with a DetachArray function that moves the array on return to the caller. Is this the best way - it seems a little complicated? Also, in this case, if I am calling the DetachArray function from C#, is the array copied or not? I don't know how the interaction between managed and unmanaged memory works. I assume that the use of com_array as opposed to std::vector has something to do with this.

Answer (score 3):

The TResult of IAsyncOperation needs to be passed is a Windows Runtime type. If you want to return an array, you could try to use [`Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.collections.ivectorview_t_) as a collection object instead of winrt::com_array. In that case, it will be convenient and doesn't need to box or unbox. For example:

```cpp
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncOperation<Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<hstring>> Class::MyMethod()
{
    Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<hstring> coll1{ winrt::single_threaded_vector<hstring>() };
    ......
    co_return coll1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I want to return an array, not a Windows Runtime object, because I need access to it to be efficient and not involve interop. It is going to be a large byte array - maybe up to 100MB, so I'm looking for the most efficient method. Also I hope someone can answer my question about whether or not the array is copied.

Comment: What's about your moving the array? Do you mean you used std::move() method? And can you show more details about how you stored the com_array and the DetachArray function?

Comment: The implementation looks like this
CustomByteArray::CustomByteArray(com_array<uint8_t>&& givenBytes) {
    swap(givenBytes, bytes);
}

com_array<uint8_t> CustomByteArray::DetachArray() {
    com_array<uint8_t> temp{};
    swap(bytes, temp);
    return temp;
}
There is a private member com_array<uint8_t> called 'bytes'. com_array has a deleted copy constructor so will be returned by move.

Comment: If you want a byte array, you can use IBuffer. Otherwise, the DetachArray appears to be making the best of a bad situation.